# nginx reverse proxy - how to rewrite a 303 location response header?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I've setup my nginx reverse proxy and I can reach my internal host without issues

However, it flicks back a 303 when initially connecting to push the client to authenticate.. and the location sent gets through as the internal server

eg:

```
Status: 303 See Other
Location: http://kaonashi.local.abc.com/auth/login
```

How can I rewrite the location header so that it is still pointing to my external address?

My config is:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl; # Make sure the 'ssl' is added here as well

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/external.abc.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/external.abc.com/privkey.pem;

        # modsecurity
        modsecurity on;
        modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

        root /var/www/external.abc.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name external.abc.com;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /leantime/ {

                proxy_set_header Host kaonashi.local.abc.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://kaonashi.local.abc.com:8080/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is changed by proxy_redirect as per http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

I had to do

```
proxy_redirect http://kaonashi.local.abc.com https://external.abc.com/leantime/;
```

then i had to add

```
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding ""; # no compression allowed or next won't work

sub_filter "http://kaonashi.local.abc.com/" "https://external.abc.com/leantime/";
sub_filter_once off;
```

to fix links inside the pages

and

```
proxy_cookie_domain kaonashi.local.abc.com external.abc.com;
```

Now all that seems to fail is when something patches the session which has the

> Host: kaonashi.local.abc.com